# jQuery не подключается к phpStorm

Tags: jquery, phpstorm

Скачал файл https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js, добавил его в HTML-документ в phpStorm, но jQuery не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может нужно что-то ещё настроить?

Comment: открой этот адрес в браузере и сохрани как query-3.3.1.min.js и подключи script src=""

Comment: в каком смысле не работает? методы не распознаются в редакторе, или код не работает в браузере?